# SQL GROUP BY result set values under a new value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, resultset

I would like to group certain values within a result set as a new value.

eg my result set is:

```
KS2
2a
3c
4c
3c
2a
2a
1c
No KS2
1b
2c
5c
4c
```

My currrent SQL at the bottom groups results in the following:

```
KS2
2a
3c
4c
1c
No KS2
1b
2c
5c
4c
```

I would like to group the values 1a, 1b and 1c into a single row under the value 1 and 2a, 2b and 2c as 2. All other values should group normally. So my result set would look like:

```
KS2
2
3c
4c
1
No KS2
5c
4c
```

Here is my code as it stands:

```
GROUP BY
CASE Name
    WHEN 'English' THEN
        CASE WHEN [Ks2en]=NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2en]
        END
    WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
        CASE WHEN [Ks2ma]=NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2ma]
        END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN [Ks2av]=NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2av]
        END
    END
```

EDIT: Here's the solution based on EricZ's answer:

```
GROUP BY
       CASE Name
            WHEN 'English' THEN
                CASE WHEN [Ks2en] IS NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2en] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                WHEN [Ks2en] IN ('2a','2b','2c') THEN 
                    '2'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2en]
                END
            WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
                CASE WHEN [Ks2ma] IS NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2ma] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                WHEN [Ks2ma] IN ('2a','2b','2c') THEN 
                    '2'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2ma]
                END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN [Ks2av] IS NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('2a','2b','2c') THEN 
                    '2'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2av]
                END
            END
```

Comment: Can you share the full query and an example of your data? What is the name column you're grouping by?

Comment: @Mureinik - I've added the full query for you. The column I'm grouping on is 'KS2' which is values in either Ks2en, Ks2ma or Ks2av depending on the contents of the SubjectName variable.

Comment: Now that's what I call job security :) Sometimes it's better to break queries out into multiple smaller ones.

Comment: @Trent note sure I follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
GROUP BY
CASE 
    WHEN Name = 'English' THEN ISNULL(NULLIF([Ks2en],''),'No KS2')
    WHEN Name = 'Mathematics' THEN  ISNULL(NULLIF([Ks2ma],''),'No KS2')   
    WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN '1'
    WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('2a','2b','2c') THEN '2'    
    ELSE ISNULL(NULLIF([Ks2av],''),'No KS2')
END
```

Please note that in your code you have `[Ks2en]=NULL` will always return false, you could use `[Ks2en] IS NULL` to check the NULL value

Comment: Hi EricZ, this is along the right lines. It is the `WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN '1'` that is of particular interest. I've applied it to my code, but the grouped values disappear from the result set. Also took on board the advise re NULLs.

Comment: I sussed it. I had a JOIN setup to another table which disn't have values again '1', so I added the values and it showed ok. Changed the JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and your code works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another table to store your "grouping behaviour". That coul be a two-column table containing entries like ('1a', '1'), ('1b', '1'), ('2a', '2'), and so on.

Heres a SQLFiddle, where a have put an example together:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deb87/7